# How to disable network access for a user?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Trying to disable the network access for the user:

```
[root@notebook ~]# iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tempuser -j DROP
[root@notebook ~]# ip6tables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner tempuser -j DROP
Could not open socket to kernel: Address family not supported by protocol
[root@notebook ~]# 
[root@notebook ~]# iptables -I INPUT -m owner --uid-owner tempuser -j DROP
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
[root@notebook ~]# ip6tables -I INPUT -m owner --uid-owner tempuser -j DROP
Could not open socket to kernel: Address family not supported by protocol
[root@notebook ~]#
```

Testing it:

```
[root@notebook ~]# su - tempuser
[tempuser@notebook ~]$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
[tempuser@notebook ~]$ 
[tempuser@notebook ~]$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.80 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=4.07 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1057ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.071/4.439/4.807/0.368 ms
[tempuser@notebook ~]$ 
[tempuser@notebook ~]$ exit
logout
[root@notebook ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bud02s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.209.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=5.05 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 572ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.059/5.059/5.059/0.000 ms
[root@notebook ~]#
```

**Question:** how can I disable the network access for a given user under Linux? (INPUT/OUTPUT/IPv4/IPv6?) - why can I still ping IPv4 addresses with the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o ethX -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j DROP
```

Where,

--uid-owner { USERNAME } : Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given effective USERNAME.
-A : Append rule to given table/chain
-I : Insert rule to head of table/chain

For example, my oracle user id is 1000 so I will append following rule:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j DROP

service iptables save
```

Comment: I can google too..... as you can see in my example, this doesn't works.

Comment: Try to access any website from the browser.... It will work. I've already tried ..that's why I posted the answer. I know you could google it too buddy.

Comment: "It will work" --- it will work to access any website OR the iptables rule will work?

Comment: iptables rule will work. That specified user will not be able to access the internet.

Comment: It blocks domains, OK, but it doesn't blocks via IP!!

Comment: the ping tricked me :) it has suid bit :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use TCP wrappers for doing this, /etc/host.allow or /ect/host.deny you can mention your network pool in this file with the users.